# Some problems using glTexImage2D and glGetTexImage

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I have run into some issues regarding `glTexImage2D()` and `glGetTexImage()`.

In my code I am trying to load an image using OpenCV's `imread()`, convert it to a texture format with a texture_id handle, and then convert it back again to a matrix type (OpenCV's `Mat`).  Somewhere along the way the data of my image seems to get lost and `image.data` returns NULL.

I suspect that the problem lies somewhere in my implementation of `matToTexture()`.

I am writing in C++ in Visual Studio 15 and using OpenCV 3.1 and OpenGL 4.4.

Texture.cpp:

```
#include "Texture.h"

Mat textureToMat(GLuint textureID);
GLuint matToTexture(Mat image);

GLuint matToTexture(Mat image) {

    GLuint texture_id;

    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Image empty." << endl;
    }

    else {

        glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RGB,
            image.cols,
            image.rows,
            0,
            GL_BGR,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            image.ptr());

    }

    return texture_id;
}

Mat textureToMat(GLuint texture_id) {

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    GLenum texture_width, texture_height, texture_format;

    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, (GLint*)&texture_width);
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, (GLint*)&texture_height);
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT, (GLint*)&texture_format);

    unsigned char* texture_bytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*texture_width*texture_height * 3);

    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_bytes);

    Mat out(texture_height, texture_width, CV_8UC3, texture_bytes);

    free(texture_bytes);

    return out;

}
```

And the header Texture.h:

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H

#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw3.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat textureToMat(GLuint textureID);
GLuint matToTexture(Mat image);

#endif /*!TEXTURE_H*/
```

And the call:

```
#include "Texture.h"

int main(){

    glfwInit();
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* offscreen_context = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(offscreen_context);

    Mat dummy = imread("mini.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    GLuint tex = matToTexture(dummy);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    Mat some = textureToMat(tex);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(offscreen_context)) {

        glfwSwapBuffers(offscreen_context);
        glfwPollEvents();

        if (glfwGetKey(offscreen_context, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(offscreen_context, GL_TRUE);
        }
    }

    glfwTerminate();


    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect `free(texture_bytes)` to be the source of the "`NULL`ness" :D. Try commenting it out.

Comment: @sarasvati is correct, `Mat out(texture_height, texture_width, CV_8UC3, texture_bytes)` only provides a shallow copy of the data, internally the Mat points to `texture_bytes` you provide, if you delete the memory, it's gone. You could do `Mat out = Mat(texture_height, texture_width, CV_8UC3, texture_bytes).clone()` to solve the problem, a better approach would be creating a Mat with the right size, and calling `glGetTexImage` on the `Mat` to avoid a copy.

Comment: Where do you create your OpenGL context?  None of those GL texture operations will work without a current GL context.  Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: Ah, I've deleted the free() operations for now then. Also, the context creation didnt even occur to me. I'm pretty new to OpenGL, so I'll try to read up on this today. Thanks guys :)

Comment: I've now updated the post to clarify the code ++. I have also tried to implement a context in the main function, but its probable that I have done this the wrong way. I still get the same error though, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You don't create an OpenGL context. Plain simple as that. Without a OpenGL context created and being active on the current thread all OpenGL function calls are no-ops.

Comment: Thanks! As you can probably tell I'm pretty new to OpenGL, so this didn't even occur to me. I'm reading up on it now.

Comment: I have tried to find information about creating a context for my use, but I am finding it hard to understand. I have updated my code above so that it is separated in .cpp, .h and call sections. Where should i state the context, and how? So far I have only found tutorials for making contexts for drawing windows, which is not what i want.

Comment: @T.Soemod: Creating a OpenGL context is (unfortunately) nontrivial. Which explains the existence of several application frameworks that deal with just that (GLUT, GLFW, SMFL, SDL). OpenGL always was focused on realtime rendering with the resulting image sent to a display. Altough OpenGL itself is window system neutral, the APIs required to actually create a OpenGL context are tied to the windowing system (WGL, GLX, NSOpenGLView).

Comment: @T.Soemod: Over the past two years a number of API that allow straight setup of an off-screen context emerged, but the usual way to create an OpenGL context still is through a window. The steps are: 1.) create a Window, 2.) configure it's framebuffer format, 3.) create a OpenGL context using the window as a template for the framebuffer format to use, 4.) make the OpenGL context active on a thread with a window that's compatible to the context's main framebuffer format. Libraries like GLUT or GLFW coalesce these steps into a single function call.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying a bit @datenwolf. Where should i write the context? Does it have to be in main(), or some other place? Would a hidden context do for my case?

Comment: I have now updated my main call with a context. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it, and I am still getting the same error.